# What is the best pattern (logic) for on-boarding sequence?

Tags: ios, swift

I have created an app, illustrated with red VC (root), and an onboarding sequence illustrated with a blue VC.  Before the user gets to the main app (red) I want to intercept the launch at the Navigation Controller and check if the user has been onboard.  What is the best pattern for doing this? Currently, no matter what logic I have in the NC, or where I put it, the red VC is always evaluated as long as it is the root VC.  What is the best pattern/setup/logic for using an on-boarding sequence with a root VC? (maybe a root VC is not necessary, I have used it because it seems to work improve launch time relative to modal segue)

[image]

**UPDATE 1:** here is SWIFT code - it works

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let isOnboarded:Bool = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("Onboarded")

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    // instantiate your desired ViewController
    let dashboardViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DashboardVC") as! UIViewController
    let onboardingViewControllerOne = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("OnboardingVCOne") as! UIViewController

    let window = self.window

    if (isOnboarded) {
            window!.rootViewController = dashboardViewController

        }else{
            window!.rootViewController = onboardingViewControllerOne
    }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic like that would sit well in the App Delegate*, in the `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method.

You'd query the `NSUserDefaults` to see if you have a `BOOL` value for a specific key like `firstRun`.
If you do then you set the blue VC as the root view controller, if not you would set the red one and persist a `BOOL` for the 'firstValue' key to `NSUserDefaults`.

*people will tell you that filling up the App Delegate with logic is a bad thing, and they are right, this however is something that is right to place there as it's called before the view hierarchy is setup.

EDIT: Here's some code. I'm writing off the top of my head so it may need tweaking to work...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  UIViewController *blue = [UIViewController new];
  UIViewController *red = [UIViewController new];
  BOOL isFirstLaunch = [[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] boolForKey:@"firstRun"];
  UIWindow *window = self.window;
  if (firstRun)
  {
    self.window.rootViewController = blue;
  }
  else 
  {
    self.window.rootViewController = red;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"firstRun"];
  }

  //...rest of method...
}
```

Comment: ahh ok, I see, that is clever.   You write:  "...if not you would set the red one and persist a BOOL for the 'firstValue' key to NSUserDefaults."  What do you mean by persist?  Can you please elaborate with some code? I should be able to find out how to set a VC as root VC

Comment: Sure let me edit the answer. I'd also say it would be good for you to read some of the Apple dis on this sort of thing so you feel a bit more at home with the concepts.

Comment: OK, done, let me know if you have other questions. If you can accept answer if you're happy with it that would be great :)

Comment: Question is updated after trying to implement your code.